# Shift + Return key action in a Cocoa App

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I have a `NSTextView`, whenever user presses on `Shift` + `Return` Key I should perform an action.

But the problem is that I could not figure out how to know whether the user pressed on `Return` key or not.

I have used this code to know whether user pressed on `Shift` key or not.

```
override func flagsChanged(theEvent: NSEvent) {

        switch theEvent.modifierFlags.intersect(.DeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask)
        {
        case NSEventModifierFlags.ShiftKeyMask :
            print("shift key is pressed")
        case NSEventModifierFlags.ControlKeyMask:
            print("control key is pressed")
        case NSEventModifierFlags.AlternateKeyMask :
            print("option key is pressed")
        case NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask:
            print("Command key is pressed")
        case NSEventModifierFlags.FunctionKeyMask:
            print("Function key is pressed")

        default:
            print("no key or more than one is pressed")
        }
    }
```

But there is no option for Return key in `NSEventModifierFlags`.

Let me know your thoughts? How will I solve this?

Comment: Please don't include the answer in your question. If an answer solved your issue, mark the answer as accepted; you can *also* post your own answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the following approach to get the keyCode to understand when it is a shift, return key or whatever you want to detect in case of having the desired key, perform your logic.

```
import Cocoa

class YourWindow: NSWindow {
    override func keyDown(event: NSEvent) {
        super.keyDown(event)
        print("Caught a key down: \(event.keyCode)!")
    }
}
```

You can also use a `keyUp` event